# how to convert document type to spark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

I'm trying to convert document type into spark RDD but I have no idea how to do that. 
Basically, I'm trying to implement Google cloud NLP API in Apache Spark. Below is my code :

EDITED

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import six
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('yarn-client').appName('SparkNLP').getOrCreate()
gcs_uri = 'gs://mybucket/reddit.json'
document = types.Document(gcs_content_uri=gcs_uri,type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
readRDD = spark.read.text(document)
```

of course the second last line will give an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 328, in text
    return self._df(self._jreader.text(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(paths)))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1248, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1218, in _build_args
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 298, in get_command_part
AttributeError: _get_object_id
```

Can anyone please guide me to the right track ?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with the `doc = document.rdd` line. Remove that and then go straight to the next line `spark.read.csv(doc)` and follow it with a map to transform the document into your preferred columns. Also, since you are trying to do something with NLP I want to just make sure that you are aware of the Spark-NLP package: https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt: spark.read.csv(doc), this statement doesn't understand document type that is why I was converting a document into RDD first.

Comment: Okay - you cannot convert an object into an RDD simply by appending `.rdd` to it. Instead, you must read in the file containing the documents as text (using `spark.read.text(doc)`) and then use `map` to convert the text into appropriate columns.

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I just edited my code..but it's giving some other error. The situation is I haven't used document type in spark before.